# Format date using WPF in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I have a DataGridthat has a Start Time column. This is bound to a string field which holds the time in the format hh:mm:ss. However, I want to only display the time in the grid in the format hh:mm. Is there a way of achieving this using the string format attribute in Binding.

Comment: Is it really `string field`?, if yes, you need converter with string manipulation.

Comment: Yes it is string format. I was wondering if stringformat had a way of dealing with string datatype. Thanks anyway.

Comment: without converter, impossible.

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyDate, StringFormat='HH:mm'}" />
```

Comment: I think this would work if the data was of datetime type. Mine is a string.

Answer (score 1):

I've exhausted my search for trying to find out if there was a way for the StringFormat attribute of Binding in WPF to convert a string to a date and then format it as HH:mm.

So I've gone about creating a converter to do the same as suggested above. Thought I'd paste it here for use by anyone who has such a need.

```
public class StringToDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        DateTime d;
        try
        {
            d = System.Convert.ToDateTime(value);
            return d;
            // The WPF code that uses this converter will then use the stringformat 
            // attribute in binding to display just HH:mm part of the date as required.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // If we're unable to convert the value, then best send the value as is to the UI.
            return value;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Insert your implementation here...
        return value;
    }
}
```

And here is how you achieve the result in WPF.

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Time"  Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding VisitOpStartTime, Converter={StaticResource s2dConverter}, StringFormat=\{0:HH:mm\}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Lastly, don't forget to add the following, customised ofcourse to your needs.

```
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:[YourAppNamespace].Converters"

    <Window.Resources>
        <converter:StringToDateConverter x:Key="s2dConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

Hope this helps.